# Generate PDF using Java or Spring

Tags: java, spring, pdf

How to Generate PDF files using  Spring or java.

There is similar question raised 9 years ago which is closed now  and all the answers are dated back to 9 years ago.

PDF generation very common at this times, and I would like to know the different libraries available now for PDF generation.

Comment: `PDFBOX`(Open Source) & `iText`(required license for commercial applications) are the 2 major libraries used to generate PDF. Anything else adding to this list will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Another ~~expensive~~ way to create PDF in java is to build an HTML using your favourite HTML templating library (like Thymeleaf, etc...) Then feed that HTML to an external application, [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), to build a PDF file. This approach is ideal to java applications that live in a server, and has a dev team that are good in writing HTML

Comment: Thanks, looks like generating html using template engine like FreeMarker and converting this html to pdf on the fly using itext ( or PDFBOX, etc.) is a good options.

Answer (score -1):

you always have the option to make an html and convert it to pdf
The following tools can help you:

[Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/pdfx.html) 
[Wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)